# Chartjs create chart with big data and fixed labels

Tags: chart.js

I want to create chart of type `line` with chatjs. The problem is, I have date formatted: `{ x: real number from 0 to 1, y: integers from 0 to infinite }`, and I want fixed labels to the chart in x-axis, something like: `[0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1]`.

This is how I'd like to set the chart configuration:

```
type: 'line',
data: {
  labels: ['0', '0.1', '0.2', '0.3', '0.4', '0.5', '0.6', '0.7', '0.8', '0.9', '1'],
  datasets: [{
    label: 'data',
    data: [
      { x: 0.3, y: 446 },
      { x: 0.3331, y: 6863 },
      { x: 0.874, y: 12 },
      { x: 0.2244, y: 1565 },
      { x: 0.38899, y: 32221 },
      { x: 0.23685545, y: 3112324 },
      { x: 0.11332, y: 444423 },
      { x: 0.97694, y: 21212334 },
    ],
  }]
},
```

But this is obviously not working, How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

So I found out there is another chart type of `scatter`. This is typically used to only points on axes chart, but it can configured to have lines between the points. Also, if marking the points on graph is unneccessary there is a configuration option to set those points' radius to `0` and this makes those hidden.

https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/scatter.html#scatter-chart